# Cannot understand why that behavior

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have this code:

```
     char *name[] = { "a1", "b2", "c3", "d4" };
     printf("%s\n", *name); //the critical line
```

Related to `critical line`:

In this form, the output is simple: `a1`.
If I replace the `critical line` with:

`printf("%s\n", ++*name);`

then the output is `1`. I think until now everything is good.

Taking in account that `name` is a pointer to the first string of characters, respectively `"a1"`, I replace the `critical line` with:

`printf("%s\n", ++name);`

in the hope that I'll get `"b2"` result as output. But I get this error:

`../src/test.c:32: error: lvalue required as increment operand`.

**Question**: I can't understand why `++*name` is legal - `name` is a pointer to first string of characters - and `++name` isn't. In my opinion, the `++name` should move the `name` to the next string of characters. Can anybody explain me where is the lack in my understing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `++name`, the *array* `name` is converted to a *pointer* to the first element of the array. The result of this conversion is not an lvalue, and it can't be modified with `++` or otherwise. You could instead write `name+1`, which would print the right thing. When `name` is an array, there is no way to modify it to refer to anything other than that array[*].

Consider also:

```
char **p = name;   // OK, `name' converts to pointer
++p;               // OK, `p' is an lvalue
++(p+1);           // not OK, `p+1' is not an lvalue
++((char**)p);     // not OK, `(char**)p' is not an lvalue

++*name;           // OK, `*name' is an lvalue
```

Roughly speaking, an "lvalue" is an expression that refers to an object, whereas a "not an lvalue" is an expression that has a value. The difference between an object and a value, is that an object is a place for storing values (well, one value at a time). Values can never be modified, objects sometimes can.

Whenever you have a subexpression which is an lvalue but whose current value is needed, the object is read/loaded/whatever you want to call it. In C++ this is called an "lvalue to rvalue conversion", I can't remember whether it's called anything in C other than "evaluating the subexpression".

[*] you can shadow it with another variable `name` in an inner scope, that refers to something else. But that's still not modifying the outer `name`, just temporarily hiding it.

Comment: See my comment to @Kerrek's response.

Answer (score 2):

`name` is an array, so, except when you use it as operand of the `sizeof` or `&` operators, it is evaluated as a pointer to the initial member of the array objet and is **not an lvalue**.

Accordingly, you can't modify `name` directly, with an operator such as `++` (remember that the postfix increment operator need a modifiable lvalue as operand). Otherwise, you can use a temporary pointer (`p` in the following example).

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *name[] = { "a1", "b2", "c3", "d4" };
const char **p = name;
printf("%s\n", *p); /* Output: a1 */
*++p; /* or *p++ */
printf("%s\n", *p); /* Output: b2 */
```

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. I just wanted to emphasize that `i` need to be a modifiable lvalue to perform this operation. NB: I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure you're totally happy and confident with the following fact: *An arrays is not a pointer.*

Second, what's in a `name`? The array *decays* into a pointer to the first element. After decay, the expression `name` has type `char **` (pointer to first element of an array of `char*`. However, the decayed expression is an *rvalue*. You cannot modify it! And naturally so, since it makes no sense to modify a pointer that's a pointer to a fixed array.

Therefore, you cannot directly increment the pointer which is the result of decaying `name`, no more than you can say `++5` or `++foo()` <s>(where `foo` returns a primitive type by value)</s><sub>[whoops, that was a concession meant for C++]</sub>.

What you *can* say is this:

```
char ** np = name;
++np;
printf("%s", *np);
```

This has the same effect as printing `name[1]`, but now you also have a variable that holds a pointer to the second array element.

Comment: "the decayed expression is an rvalue" - or in C standard terminology, it's the "result of an expression". Stupid C standard terminology. Likewise, in C, a function call `foo()` can't return an lvalue.

Comment: Even weirder, after I execute your code I get binary string, like this: $�'�*�@�� instead of `"b2"`. What's the explanation?

Comment: @artaxerxe: I can't reproduce that: http://ideone.com/S63K7. Maybe there's something else wrong with the code you ran.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Oh whoops, this is C and not C++ :-S Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @SteveJessop I forgot to put dereferencing sign (*) on the last line. I beg your pardon :)

Comment: @Kerrek: My rule of thumb is that if a question mentioning `char*` is more than 10 seconds old, and there are no comments saying "use `string` instead", then I should carefully examine the tags ;-)

Answer (score 1):

While name points to the address of the first element, name is not of `type char *`, but `char *[4]`. therefore, `sizof(name) == sizeof(char *)*4`

Incrementing a pointer always means to add the size of the data it points to. So, after incrementing, it points **behind** the whole array. Just like if you have

```
    int i, a;
    int *p = &i;
    p++;
```

p will now point **behind** i. It will point to a, if the compiler decided to put a behind i.

Also note that your array only contains 4 pointers, not 4 strings. Like above, it is the compilers choice where those strings actually are. So, the end of the first string is not necessarily next to the beginning of the second string. Especially if you assign other values (string adresses) to name[1] later. Therefore, you may cast name to `char **`, but should not cast to `char *`. Incrementing the former will point to the second element (second char* pointer).